# phing FtpDeploy "connection to host failed"

Tags: deployment, phing

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy a ZIP file to a remote FTP server. I tried connecting to the server using an FTP client (filezilla) and all goes well.

Also, when connecting to a public ftp like ftp.belnet.be connections work fine. 
I'm trying to send the file to a VSFTPD server behind a router using port forwarding. Again, this works fine from any location using Filezilla, phing is not connecting though...

BUILD FAILED
/deployment/build.xml:60:12: Could not connect to FTP server x.x.x.x on port 21: Connection to host failed

Total time: 2 minutes  30.09 seconds

Comment: I'm using phing version 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a firewall issue that has been resolved.